# Adjective for having enough and satisfactory food

Tags: phrase-request, adjectives, vocabulary, food

I have eaten enough food. The food was delicious and may be I have eaten a lot more than required. I enjoyed it. Now I am very happy about it. How to describe this? Should we say "I have had enough food/ satisfactory meal" or should it be "a decent meal". Somebody suggested me "bellyful" which I don't think is right in this situation because 'bellyful' talks about only quantity. Please suggest right vocabulary.

Comment: *Well-fed* is the first thing that comes to mind.

Comment: I would be very surprised if this would count as English idiom, but my grandfather used to say after a such a meal:
_If things don't change, I'll never eat again_.
This referred both to his full belly and the feeling of satisfaction because of the quality of the meal.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to say this, some more colloquial than others.

The most common in my experience is "full".

> **I'm full**.  I **couldn't eat another bite**.

Others:

> I'm **stuffed**.
>
> I'm **satisfied**
>
> I'm **satiated**.
>
> I **couldn't eat another thing**.

Some colorful colloquialisms

> I'm stuffed to the gills
>
> If I eat any more I'll pop.
>
> If I eat any more you'll have to cart me out in a wheelbarrow.
>
> I'm stuffed like a turkey

I'm sure there are dozens more, but that's all I can come up with for now.